# Does every form and/or console application require installation?

Tags: winforms, installation, console-application

Let's say that I have created a form or a console application. This form application's only dependency is .NET Framework (not a 3rd library) and application doesn't have any kind of requirements. What it does is to take a file and transforms to something else.

Does this application need to be installed? Can I just copy .exe file that is under \bin folder and share it?

Comment: For any .Net app, you can copy the files to any machine and the app will run, provided the machine has the relevant .Net Framework version installed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that Copy Local is set to true for all the references of your start up project. Setting copy local to true will make sure that the DLLs get copied to the output directory. Then, build the solution and copy all the files from your output directory to any machine where you want to run the application. The application should work, as long as it has the appropriate .NET framework installed.

Here's a link about how to set copy local to true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Ways to Do This... I just did this 20 Min Ago :)

- Method 1 : Right Click on Your Project, Publish, Choose Location For
  The installer. This installer can be copied onto other machines, installed and run
- Method 2 : Your bin/release folder will contain .exe files which need to be copied and Installed, i prefer the 1st method. It avoids missing important / Needed Files for execution

**Just a Side Note. Make Sure the Output Type Is of Console Type (Right Click on project... Output type...), Some windows applications give Problems when Publishing and Installing them due to the frameworks that might be missing**